# how can we set the iconfile name property of window?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am creating login page in oracle form now I want to change the default icon with my custom icon of WINDOW

How to achieve this target?

[image]

Comment: What icon are you talking about, exactly? Could you post a screenshot and mark it?

Comment: @Littlefoot (WINDOW1)

Comment: What did you try already? Google gives multiple results for your problem, why aren't they feasible? https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+form+change+icon

Answer (score 0):

We can not customize `smart toolbar` of *Oracle Forms*, but we can replace it with a new one.

For this aim ( assuming you have *Fusion Middleware 11g* ):

Run *cmd.exe* (on *Windows*)
 and type ( as an example ):

```
C:\Users\Ramiz.Tariq> cd C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\ohs\icons
```

where you may find tons of *gif*s. And then *jar.exe* with *-cvf* option :

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\ohs\icons> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\jdk\bin
      \jar.exe -cvf myToolbar.jar *.gif
added manifest
adding: a.gif(in = 246) (out= 237)(deflated 3%)
adding: alert.black.gif(in = 242) (out= 233)(deflated 3%)
adding: alert.red.gif(in = 247) (out= 243)(deflated 1%)
adding: apache_pb.gif(in = 2326) (out= 1698)(deflated 26%)
.....
adding: forward.gif(in = 219) (out= 211)(deflated 3%)
.....
```

*Move* your newly created *.jar* file to the *jdk\bin* directory.

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\ohs\icons>move myToolbar.jar 
                                      C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\jdk\bin
```

Edit your *formsweb.cfg* file to introduce this new *jar* file to your *Forms* :

by converting line `archive=frmall.jar` to `archive=frmall.jar, myToolbar.jar`, and do not forget to save it.

Now you're ready to create and customize your toolbar of forms ;

- From *Property Palette* at the *forms* level, convert *Menu Module* property from `default&smartbar` to `default`.
- Create a Horizontal Toolbar at the top of the Window with *Bevel*
  property *Raised* and add some buttons on it with *Iconic Property*
  set to `Yes`, and `Icon Filename`s defined such as `forward.gif`,
  `folder.open.gif` etc.(you may add more gif to this folder before
  creating *myToolbar.jar* file)

[image]

When you run below view will appear on the screen

( *PENCERE* is equivalent of *WINDOW* in my mother tongue ):

[image]